# Как сделать, чтобы PyQt5 не зависал?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, captcha

У меня стоит задача обработки капчи из ВКонтакте с помощью приложения. Но когда я получаю капчу, то у меня зависает программа.

Я погуглил, и в итоге пришел к выводу, что это из за `time.sleep()`, и нужно решать как-то через потоки, но до меня вообще не доходит.

Код:

```
class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        #Создание виджетов

    def change(self):
        #Отправка поста
        try:
            self.session_api_vk.wall.post(owner_id=-34985835, from_group=0, message='mess')
        except:
            pass

    #Выполняется при обработки капчи
    def captcha_handler(self, captcha):
        self.uncapcha(captcha.get_url())
        while self.txt == '':
            sleep(5)
        a = self.txt
        self.txt = ''
        return captcha.try_again(a)

    #Вызывается когда пользователь введет и нажмет Enter
    def gotovo(self):
        self.txt = self.input.text()

    def uncapcha(self, url):
        data = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, r"путь")
        self.pixmap = QPixmap(r"путь")
        self.lbl.setPixmap(self.pixmap)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку "**начать**", входит в работу функция `change`, она отправляет пост, где появляется капча.

Далее для решения капчи вызывается функция `captcha_handler`, в которой вызывается функция `uncaphca`, **в которой выводит в Label картинку капчи**.

Далее включается 5-секундный таймер, который проверяет, есть ли текст в `self.txt`

А записывается сюда текст, когда пользователь в `lineedit` нажмет кнопку на клавиатуре `Enter`, вызовется функция `gotovo` и `self.txt` присваивается текст, который ввел пользователь, но программа зависает на моменте цикла с таймером.

Answer (score 2):

PyQt не позволит тебе взаимодействовать с GUI не из основного потока, для создания многопоточного приложение нужно использовать класс QThread входящий в набор PyQt. А для взаимодействия должны использоваться сигналы и слоты. [Вот туториал](https://nikolak.com/pyqt-threading-tutorial/) который тебе поможет.